# Boot 2 different versions of Ubuntu on the same computer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am completely ignorant about how Grub works, I want to have two different versions of Ubuntu 22.04 installed on the same computer and have both of them appear in the Grub boot menu. The two versions are installed on different physical drives. Currently, when I install the second version it overwrites the Grub entries from the first installation, thus making it inaccessible. Must I edit the Grub configuration, and if so, how, or is there something I can do when installing the second version of Ubuntu to prevent it from overwriting the Grub configuration?

Comment: Installing Boot-Repair from ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair in an Ubuntu USB live session and then running Boot-Repair should be able to fix this problem. Otherwise please edit your question if you get an error message.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs? Both must be in same boot mode.  Better to post link from Boot-Repair's summary report so we can see details. I have several installs on multiple drives and boot all from one grub menu, but often add ESP - efi system partition to second drive for direct boot from UEFI,if issues. Did you run `sudo update-grub`. For a while os-prober was turned off, but I think it defaults to back on now. Last install or major update will be default, but just boot into other install & reinstall grub to make it default.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you installed the two systems on different drives without making an "lvm" . it means the boot sequence of your bios has been altered to the and the second drive seems to come first in the boot sequence, so to be able to choose one system to boot from during boot, depending on your machine you have to access the boot menu and choose the drive from which you want to boot
hint: you can try `F12, F9 or F10`  during bios startup

hope this helps you ...

Comment: I have attempted to use boot-repair as suggested by another user and the results were disappointing. The system would only boot into emergency mode in the first instance of Ubuntu installed and would never complete booting again.

Comment: have you tried modifying the boot sequence and placing the system you to boot from as first drive and it didn't worked ? . if yes please explain the outcome else you may try that too.